# Is there a way to do fine grained access control in ASPNET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The new authorize attribute in ASPNET 5 seems to cover simple apps with course access control fine. But how would one go about using it with 10+ controllers with CRUD operations? 
Is it correct to add policies for all calls, since there is no way to pass required claims to the policies?
It seems this list would be impossible to manage and clutter the ConfigureService method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write policies which require claims and their values;

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireRead", 
                      policy => policy.RequireClaim("DocumentPermission", "Read"));
}
```

It depends how you model your claim values. If you have a claim value of, for example, "CRUD" to indicate a user has create, read, update and delete for that particular claim then you're going to have to write your own requirement and handler.

Comment: Ok. I think this might work, but why not have an AuthorizeAttribute with a possibility to pass params to the attached policy? Then you could have one policy to handle multiple claims.
Ex. 
`[ClaimAuthorizeAttribute("ReadPolicy", "requiredClaim")]

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireRead", 
                      policy => policy.RequireClaim({requiredClaim}, "Read"));
}
`

Then you could have one handler for all read claims.

Comment: You can. You can parameterise requirements.

Comment: Yes but i would still need to add 100s of policies to cover our fine grained authorization. Since each policy basically will cover one claim. Would you then recommend we use something like CRUD as claim value and add one policy for each claim?

Comment: You could simply have one policy and do what you did in the custom attribute. It'd be a huge ball of mess but then so was the the attribute code.